URL Length Limit and Query Parameter Constraints in Front-End to Back-End Requests
While developing a mechanism for front-end requests to the back-end, I've encountered an issue regarding the URL length when carrying multiple query parameters. Is there a length limit for URLs? If so, what exactly is the limit? Additionally, is there a maximum number of query parameters that can be sent in a single request? I'm looking for relevant standards or documentation that address these questions and would also appreciate insights into the different limits imposed by browsers and servers.
What I’ve Tried:
Reviewed Browser Documentation: I examined the documentation for browsers like Chrome and Firefox and found that most modern browsers support URLs up to approximately 2000 characters. However, I couldn't find a definitive standard.
Checked Server Documentation: I looked into the official documentation for servers like Apache and IIS. Apache's default URL length limit is 8192 characters (8KB), and IIS has a default limit of 16384 characters (16KB). Nonetheless, I still need to determine the best practice.
Practical Testing: I conducted some tests in our actual project and noticed that very lengthy URLs can cause request failures, but the precise reasons and standards remain unclear.
What I’m Looking For:
I’m hoping to get clear answers to the following:
What is the URL length limit? Are there specific limits for different browsers and servers?
What is the maximum number of query parameters that can be sent in a single request?
Are there any relevant standards or reference documents that I can consult?

There is no URL length limit in the RFC, although the domain part is recommended to stay below 255 chars.  There might be limits in individual web servers.  Best practice is to have the data in a lengthy URL be sent as POST data.

I did some testing for various browsers today, and found modern browsers support at least 65,536 character URI length. I tested a 65,508 byte GET variable (https://www.example.com/?test=[laksdjfklasjdfklajf...]) and echoed the length from Django's runserver to see if each of the following browser combinations would support the full length (in Django, print(len(request.GET.get("test", "")))).
As you have noticed, your web server might have to be configured to support this length. You could do this in Apache's configuration by changing the directive to LimitRequestLine 65546.
BRAVE ON WINDOWS: 65508 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

EDGE ON WINDOWS: 65508 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/129.0.0.0

FIREFOX ON WINDOWS: 65508 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:132.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/132.0

BRAVE ON MAC: 65508 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

FIREFOX ON MAC: 65508 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0

SAFARI ON MAC: 65508 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.6 Safari/605.1.15

I didn't find any modern browsers that did not support less than Django's runserver 65,536 character URI limit, and I did not test on Linux.
